# How to clone my Dual Boot from HDD to SSD?

Tags: dual-boot, ssd, gparted, cloning

I tried doing it with Gparted but GRUB is working well, but the OS refuses to load. The OS on my SSD is not loading, and is still only mounting OS from HDD. Please help.

[image: screenshot of issue]

GRUB is working, but newly installed Ubuntu  is not running. The other OS is still running from HDD.

Comment: What do you mean "clone?" Are you trying to run Ubuntu on the SSD instead of the HDD (copy Ubuntu onto the SSD from HDD?)

Comment: Yes, I copied my Ubuntu from HDD to SSD and tried running it. As I have customized it and got some software installed.

Answer (score 3):

Open `gparted` in Ubuntu. Right click on the partition and choose properties.

You will see the `UUID` of that partition.

Copy the UUID and paste it in a text editor program with the name of the partition.

Do this for each partition. (Ex. `/boot`, `/`, `swap`, and your Windows partition(s).

Then, as root, you have to change your `/etc/fstab` file. Make a backup first!

Match every partition name with its UUID.

When everything matches, save `/etc/fstab`.

From then on it should use the partitions of your SSD.
What you also to change are the UUID's in `grub.cfg` in "/boot/grub" (as root). See picture.[image]
[image: picture of operations using GUI]

Comment: Another UUID to change is the in the stub .../EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg  Make it the one on the SSD root.

Comment: Since im new to this, @ubfan1 can you provide a video on it? It would be of great help cause i dont want to install ubuntu and windows again

Comment: @Gokul Lohiya Sorry don't know of any video, the comment was just to make the answer more complete by including the UUID used in the ESP which sets up the grub menu, which might be the old one, depending upon how the clone was made.

Comment: I have edited my answer. please take a look at it. Added some text and a screenshot of grub.cfg. Change the UUID's in that file as well. ( Response to the good comment from @ubfan1.) For video please check out youtube. We cannot add those on this forum (as far as I know).

Answer (score 0):

If you copy the HDD to the SSD, it will, most likely, not work. You can create a partition image in the Ubuntu Disks application. This is what I would try, and I don't know if it will work. After you create the partition image, select "benchmark" and set it to restore onto your SSD. It should also copy the properties, including the UUID.

If this doesn't work (I honestly don't think it will) use an Ubuntu installation disk to install Ubuntu on the SSD, delete the /home directory on the SSD, and copy the /home directory from the HDD to the SSD.